# Laravel 5.3 Data does not show

Tags: php, laravel

I'm new to laravel, I'm currently using laravel 5.3. 
I had an issue with read data from database.

here's my index code.

```
<div class="table-responsive">
                        <table class="table table-bordered">
                            <tr>
                                <th>Firs Name</th>
                                <th>Last Name</th>
                                <th>Gender</th>
                                <th colspan="2">#</th>
                            </tr>
                            @foreach((array ) $obj as $driver)
                            <tr>
                                <td>{{ $driver->first_name }}</td>
                                <td>{{ $driver->last_name }}</td>
                                <td>{{ $driver->gender }}</td>
                                <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-success" href="{{ route('driver.edit',$driver->id) }}"> Edit </button></td>
                                <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" href="{{ route('driver.destroy',$driver->id) }}" onsubmit="ConfirmDelete()"> Delete </button></td>
                            </tr>
                            @endforeach
                        </table>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" href="{{ route('driver.create') }}"> Create </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

function ConfirmDelete()
{
    var x = confirm("Are you sure want to delete?");
    if (x)
        return true;
        else
            event.preventDefault();
        return false;
}
```

DriverController

```
class DriverController extends MasterController
{
protected $indexView = 'driver.index';
protected $title = 'driver';
protected $formView = 'driver.form';
protected $editView = 'driver.edit';
protected $routeBindModel = 'driver'; 
protected $redirectPageWhenFormSuccess = 'driver.index'; //Route Name

public function save(Request $request, $obj = null) {

    if (!$obj) {
        $obj = new Driver;
    }
    $obj->first_name = $request->first_name;
    return $this->saveHandler($request, $obj);
   }
  }
```

no data and error found, I have atleast 1 data at mydatabase. input manual.

Comment: Try printing wats inside `$obj` first

Comment: @SulthanAllaudeen u mean by using echo('$obj'); at the index ?

Comment: No, `print_r($obj);`

Comment: @SulthanAllaudeen where should i put that code?

Comment: Just print in your view

Comment: @SulthanAllaudeen cant. nothing change. and also, it didn't show my button, as you can see in my code. I'm using button edit and delete.

Comment: So you have nothing in the $obj, Why not you check whether you assign something to $obj in your controller itself ?

Comment: $this->saveHandler is your custom function in your controller or it is laravel save method in laravel 5.3 because i am using laravel 5 since it is published but never heard about that function.

Answer (score 0):

I use the same technique in my Laravel project. Here I think you made a mistake.

Javascript code must be inside script tags

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function ConfirmDelete()
{
var x = confirm("Are you sure want to delete?");
if (x)
    return true;
    else
        event.preventDefault();
    return false;
}
</script>
```

I hope this will help you.